# What is the correct pronunciation of the word "Islam"?

Tags: pronunciation

Some people pronounce the **S** in *Islam* as **Z**, and others pronounce it as **S**.

Which is correct?

Comment: Not being of English tongue, I would jump and say **S**. Yslām'.

Comment: I don’t think this question is so much “not a real question” as much as it is argumentative, as is evident by didactic tone of the questioner’s own answer. I hope that the questioner has learned, from @RegDwight’s answer, that the pronunciations he considers incorrect are, in fact, considered correct by major English dictionaries.

Comment: @Nohat Is there something wrong with my didactic tone? All I mean is to try to explain the difference in meaning of both words! Why? Because I always believed that one should pronounce, or at least try to pronounce, any foreign language the way its people do; I myself would be glad if an English language expert like you helps me correct something about English.

Comment: @Dia: that is excellent reasoning, now let's put it into practice! When speaking Arabic, let us pronounce, or at least try to pronounce, all words the way native Arabic speakers do. And when speaking English, let us pronounce, or at least try to pronounce, all words the way native English speakers do.

Comment: @RegDwight In my community, my friends and I are used to merge Arabic and English words in one sentence; would you suggest then that I don't care about how to pronounce English words? I don't think so! (and by the way, I'm always keen to correct any mis-pronunciation for any one and in any language). My idea is simple: When you know, teach as many as you can, and when you don't, learn as much as you can.

Comment: @Dia: nowhere in my comments did I presume to suggest how you and your friends should be talking to each other. I am merely saying that *Islam*, *sputnik*, *Texas*, *kindergarten*, *karate* and countless others are not alien words that English-speaking people add to their conversation out of nowhere, mixing them with English words. Much rather, they are themselves English words now; and they have been for long. Really, I cannot put it any more succinctly than nohat: "Islam is now as much an English word as it is an Arabic word, and speakers of English decide how English words are pronounced."

Comment: @Dia Do you suggest that English speakers should pronounce the word *octopus* the way they say it today in Greece? Or that we should pronounce the word *jasmine* the way they say it today in Iran? Should we take advice from the Italians on how to say the word *miniature*? The answer to all these questions is, of course, “no”, because all those words are now English words, with English pronunciations that are different from the source language. The story is the same with *Islam*.

Comment: Assuming the original pronunciation uses [s], I think there's a more interesting question: why are English speakers using [z] instead? Does English have a tendency to voice between voiced segments?

Comment: It is interesting to note that the NZ media seems to have deliberately changed from 'Islamist', where the emphasis was on the second syllable, to 'Izlumist', with emphasis on the third syllable.

Comment: The new emphasis is on -ist? Or do you mean that it's on the first syllable (Iz-)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looking at the other answers, I would like to intervene. Whatever the correct pronunciation in Arabic is, we are talking about English here. Merriam-Webster [lists](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/islam) quite a few variations:

> \is-ˈläm, iz-, -ˈlam, ˈis-ˌ, ˈiz-ˌ\

It also provides two audio recordings, one for /ɪsˈlɑːm/ and one for /ɪzˈlæm/.

The Wiktionary [says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Islam#Pronunciation):

> **Pronunciation**
>
> - enPR: ĭs-läm', IPA: /ɪsˈlɑːm/, SAMPA: /Is"lA:m/
> - enPR: ĭz-läm', IPA: /ɪzˈlɑːm/, SAMPA: /Iz"lA:m/
> - enPR: ĭz'lăm, IPA: /ˈɪzlæm/, SAMPA: /"Izl{m/

Again, with all due respect to other languages, we just don't pronounce *matador* the way it is pronounced in Spanish, *sputnik* the way it is pronounced in Russian, or *kindergarten* the way it is pronounced in German.

Comment: @RegDwight You are right to some extent, but considering that Muslims account for 19.2% of the world's population, then pronouncing "Islam" wrongly is not preferable, especially when it has another meaning in its original language, i.e. Arabic.

Comment: @Dia: I am not teaching Muslims how to pronounce *Islam*, they know it very well. I am merely pointing out that there are other pronunciations that are very popular among native speakers of English and even listed in dictionaries. Which I certainly may do on a site about "English language and usage". I will also point out that there are countless English words that are not pronounced "correctly" in Arabic, Mandarin or Russian, but I don't think that it is preferable to tell *those* people that they've got it all "wrong".

Comment: @RegDwight: Why is it not preferable to tell those people that they've got it wrong? (Especially proper nouns like Sputnik, Islam, Pakistan, Kung Fu: is there a reason it's preferable that these be pronounced incorrectly in English, or any other language?)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: because it is infeasible. There are billions of people, thousands of languages, and innumerable words that have been, are being, or will be borrowed. Any mission to correct everybody on everything is doomed. In fact, even much smaller missions are doomed. Kansas is pronounced /k(ə)nˈzas/ in Russian, and Texas is pronounced /tʲɪˈxas/. Now let's try and convince those 150,000,000 people to pronounce things "correctly". No, wait, I have an even better idea: let's teach *Americans* how to pronounce "Texas" correctly. It's a Spanish word, after all.

Comment: *Telling* something to a few people is never infeasible. Just because you can never get everyone (or even a large number) to change doesn't mean there's anything wrong with telling as many people as you can. You seemed to be actually claiming there's something wrong about telling people the right pronunciation; hence my comment.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I apologize for leaving that impression, that's certainly not what I meant. I would be lying if I pretended that I have never corrected anyone's pronunciation of any word in any language. I will also add that personally, I tend to pronounce Islam as /ɪsˈlɑːm/, but only thanks to pure chance or inertia (that's the way it's pronounced in both of my mother tongues). But my point still stands, and I still think that my answer had to be added to counterbalance the other ones so far. There might be a *politically* correct pronunciation, but that is a different question altogether.

Comment: I agree completely. :-)

Comment: As a side note, sometimes Merriam-Webster notes (with a ÷ sign) when a pronunciation is common but considered incorrect by a significant number of people, for example the ‘nucular’ pronunciation of "[nuclear](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nuclear)". None of the pronunciations of *Islam*, including those with a /z/ sound, are so marked, so at least the editors of the Merriam-Webster dictionary do not find any of those pronunciations to be unacceptable. They do note that generally the first pronunciation is “preferred”, and that is the one that the original questioner prefers too.

Comment: …but let us not confuse less-preferred pronunciations with incorrectness. *Islam* is now as much an English word as it is an Arabic word, and speakers of English decide how English words are pronounced.

Comment: @cindi: Obviously, there was a point in history when the Arabic pronunciation was not just the most popular/correct one, *it was the only one, period*. All the other pronunciations developed later. So, even if it were possible to flip a switch and reset the pronunciation to the default one, globally, for every single person on this planet, *even then* there would be no guarantee whatsoever that the very same variations wouldn't develop *yet again* some time down the line. In short: 1) we are too late to the party, and 2) even if we weren't, if would make no difference in the long run.

Comment: @RegDwight: Long run, all languages are dead. Right now, each person that flips builds a bridge.

Comment: @RegDwight I've toggled off the selection of this answer to draw the audience attention back to the question cuz the discussion is still going on.

Comment: @Dia: no stress, that's fine with me (and even if it weren't, you wouldn't exactly need my permission or anything).

Comment: @cindi: you would be hard-pressed to find anyone on this page who is against building bridges. However, building bridges is one thing, but declaring one pronunciation as "correct" is a different thing entirely. That is all I am saying. Again, I pronounce *Islam* in the same way as you and Dia, and I think it's safe to say that so does a majority of the English-speaking world. However, that doesn't mean that other popular pronunciations are "wrong". Each person that flips builds a bridge, yes. But flipping goes both ways, and bridges are best build from both sides of the chasm.

Answer (score 6):

Well, "**Islam**" (and consequently all words derived from it) is pronounced correctly with an **S** not a **Z**.

And the importance of this distinction is that "**Izlam**" in Arabic means "*getting dark*", whereas "**Islam**" (with S) means "***submission***".

Comment: Although there is the discussion elsewhere in the thread about *Islam* being an English word with all deviation in pronunciation that comes with it (and I agree with this), I do think your point is quite useful to be aware of: Many Muslims — even in English-speaking communities — might consider the [ɪz] pronunciation to be an indicator of some level of ignorance about Islam (rightly or wrongly).  So, it is probably good to be at least aware of this if you are having a conversation where the topic and audience makes this important.

Comment: @ Kosmonaut Glad that you've got my point this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If native English speaking Muslims (of whom there are many) favour 'Isslam', then this pronunciation has some authority. You are an authority on the pronunciation of your own religion, just as you are on the pronunciation of your own name.

It would be interesting to know the Native English speaking Muslim pronunciation.

Comment: Being spoken by a muslim or non muslim doesnt change the english pronunciation of the word. (See accepted answer). Its just that muslims are invariably exposed to the Arabic pronunciation and they start using it more commonly. it doesnt change the english pronunciation.

Comment: In addition to what @Midhat says, I would like to point out that there are quite a few different pronunciations of the word "Christianity" as well. Who's the authority on *that* one? The Pope? He's got a German accent...

Comment: @Midhat: Don't forget that both the [s] and [z] pronunciations are considered valid English variants, and that even some native-English-speaking, non-Muslim Americans use the [s] pronunciation.  So, saying the [s] version is still English too.  (By the same logic, though, I think we must consider [z] a valid variant, whether it is pronounced that way by English-speaking Muslims or not.)

Answer (score -1):

The way native English speakers pronounce this word is changing. The proportion who say ‘Izzlum’ is going down and they tend to be older. I hear a lot more ‘Isslahm’ now.

Comment: Could you provide a source to illustrate your claim? This may also help add more useful detail, like what dialects or countries you refer to as "native" speakers.

Comment: I live in Canada. My source is my own experience of listening to people in North America and the British Isles. I presume others must have noticed this as well.