# Why is "bream" pronounced as "brim"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

Every time I catch an *Acanthopagrus australis*, commonly known as a yellowfin bream, I wonder why its name is prounced "brim", (as in the same way you would pronounce the brim of a hat).

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bream) does list the secondary pronunciation, [/**brēm**/](http://www.merriam-webster.com/audio.php?file=bream001&word=bream&text=%5C%3Cspan%20class%3D%22unicode%22%3E%CB%88%3C%2Fspan%3Ebrim%2C%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%22unicode%22%3E%CB%88%3C%2Fspan%3Ebr%C4%93m%5C). However, when I first uttered the word in that manner, I was immediately admonished by at least three people who were within earshot, and quickly learnt that fishermen (or at the very least, Australian ones,) always say **/brɪm/**.

Why is this the case? Does it have something to do with the way in which the name was derived?

Comment: Southern Louisiana fisherman say brim and probably would spell it incorrectly if pressed to write it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that it used to be pronounced *brim* in parts of the U.K. as well. From The [Edinburgh encyclopedia (1830)](http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=bream+brim&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_max%3aDec%2031_2%201840&num=10#sclient=psy&hl=en&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_max%3ADec+31_2+1840&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=fish+brim&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=37440b1e7c8375bc&biw=818&bih=398), we have

> On the coasts of Barbary is found the greatest abundance of excellent fish, particularly mullet, brim, anchovies, sardines, herring, mackarel, cod, skaite, soles, plaice, turbot, turtle.

So presumably, both pronunciations existed in the U.K. at one point, but *bream* has become the accepted pronunciation in the U.K., while *brim* is the accepted one in Australia.

Comment: I could believe that, given how close the two vowel sounds are in an Edinburgh accent.

Answer (score 8):

In Britain, bream rhymes with dream, so part of your question "why is bream pronounced as it is [in Australia]" generalises to the question "how did Australian accents come to differ from British accents?". This is an interesting bit on the Australian vowel shift and how it started to have an affect within just a few generations: http://clas.mq.edu.au/voices/history-accent-change .

Comment: The fact that *Merriam-Webster* and *American Heritage* give both *breem* and *brim* as pronunciations means that some Americans also pronounce it like this (I'd guess fishermen, who are familiar with the word). So it's not the Australian accent. My best guess was that it used to be pronounced like *brim* in at least some U.K. dialects as well, but the spelling pronunciation eventually replaced it. I don't believe this same bizarre vowel change is likely to happen independently in both Australia and the U.S.

Comment: @Peter Shor: shortening a vowel is not a particularly bizarre change, but your point about US usage is well taken.

Comment: @Peter Shor, @Rhodri: I'm struggling to think of any other words in which the *ea* would be pronounced by an Australian (or anyone else, for that matter), as the /ɪ/ vowel sound.

Comment: @Peter Shor, There isn't anything bizarre as such about the vowel shifts from UK to Australian and US pronunciations. They did happen independently but according to similar mechanisms, so it wouldn't be very strange if they had the same effect on certain words. But maybe you're right, and bream was (maybe still is) pronounced to rhyme with _him_ in parts of the UK.

Comment: @jaybee, @Rhodri: can you think of any other words which are pronounced with /iː/ in the U.K. and /ɪ/ in both Australia and the U.S? If you can, I'll take back the word *bizarre*.

Comment: Okay ... there's another one: *"creek/crick"*. But the OED traces this pronunciation back to 16th century England.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, we do pronounce it */briːm/* as you were expecting, so the derivation of the name isn't likely to be much of a factor.  It's more likely that it's a cultural shift in Australian pronunciation, though that's only a guess.

[According to Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=bream&searchmode=none) *bream* a 14th century word, coming from the Old French *braisme.*

Comment: It's not just Australia. The *Merriam-Webster* and *American Heritage* dictionaries give both pronunciations, and these dictionaries don't care a fig about how things are pronounced in Australia. Both pronunciations must be used in the U.S. My guess is that both pronunciations were formerly used in the U.K. as well. One pronunciation gave rise to the spelling, and the other pronunciation emigrated to Australia.

Comment: @Peter: Or perhaps was transported.